# FileUploader in asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

i am using fileuploader, i got its code from

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Implementing_HTTP_File_Up.aspx

and its working fine with small size files but its showing me bellow text when i try to upload a large file. my file size can be of 8-10 mb.:

```
The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
    *   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
          moments.
    *   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
          connection.
    *   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
          that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

please tell me what should i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try increasing the maximum request length in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- The value is in KB -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i have tried it and set it to 10000 as my data will be of size around 8-10 mb. but still its same. no improvement. plez suggest me any other thing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alongside the answer Darin Dimitrov has given, you might also have to change the setting in iis for your web-application.  If you are using Sharepoint, you need to configure it also in SCA.